# el while muestra n-1 registros

Tags: php, sql, web

saludos a todos, sigo con el mismo problema y no lo puedo solucionar, espero me puedan orientar, tengo un detalle que cuado utilizo la función $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); no me muestra todos los registros de mi base de datos, siempre me muestra n-1, por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta base si utilizo la función $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); con la varaible siglo xx1 y luego uso echo print_r($mostrar); me sale lo siguiente Array ( [0] => 6 [Id_cliente] => 6 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpE9W.png) => carlos [nombre_cliente] => carlos [2] => mejia [apellido_paterno_cliente] => mejia [3] => chavez [apellido_materno_cliente] => chavez [4] => carlos@cdf.mx [correo] => carlos@cdf.mx [5] => siglo xx1 [hospital] => siglo xx1 [6] => 2147483647 [telefono] => 2147483647 [7] => 111 [extension] => 111 [8] => 554326789 [celular] => 554326789 [9] => 2022-05-11 [fecha_nacimineto] => 2022-05-11 [10] => 03:45:00 [horario_disponible_inicio] => 03:45:00 [11] => 15:07:00 [horario_disponible_ifin] => 15:07:00 [12] => ventas [cargo] => ventas [13] => xochitepec [direccion_hosp] => xochitepec ) 1
me muestra un registro y el otro lo pone en 1

y después pongo la variable en ángeles por ejemplo y hago el mismo procedimiento solo me sale de resultado un 1, alguien que me oriente

Comment: Pon el código completo para que podamos ayudarte, no veo el `while`

Comment: no entiendo tu código ...